# JSONSchema and validating sub-object properties

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema

Given this JSON object:

```
{
    "objects": {
        "foo": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Foo"
        },
        "bar": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Bar"
        }
    }
}
```

This is an object containing sub objects where each sub object has the same structure - they're all the same type.  Each sub-object is keyed uniquely, so it acts like a named array.

I want to validate that each object within the `objects` property validates against a JSON Schema reference.

If the `objects` property was an array, such as:

```
{
  "objects": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Foo"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Bar"
    }  
  ]
}
```

I could validate this with a schema definition such as:

```
{
  "id": "my-schema",
  "required": [
    "objects"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "objects": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "id",
          "name"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is achieved because the `type` is `array`, and this permits the validation of `items`.

Is it possible to do something similar, but with nested objects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can try something like this:

```
{
  "id": "my-schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "objects": {
      "type": "object",
      "patternProperties": {
        "[a-z]+": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "name": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "required": [
            "id",
            "name"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The above answer works for restricting the object property names to lower-case letters.  If you do not need to restrict the property names, then this is simpler:

```
{
  "id": "my-schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "objects": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string                }
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "id",
          "name"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I omitted the inner `"additionalProperties": false` from the above answer because I find that using that keyword causes more problems than it solves, but it is a valid use of the keyword if you want validation to fail on the inner objects if they have properties other than "name" and "id".